# combine two arrays of possibly different sizes into hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, hash

How can I combine these two arrays in to a hash. They may be of equal sizes or not.

```
@status_array = ["ready", "required", "processing", "approval", "live"]

@part_milestones = [#<Milestone id: 657707, data_type: "ready">, #<Milestone id: 657708, data_type: "required">, #<Milestone id: 657709, data_type: "approval">]
```

They are sorted already. I just need the hash to deal with the "blanks" properly like so:

```
{"ready"=>#<Milestone id: 657707, data_type: "ready">, "required"=>#<Milestone id: 657708, data_type: "required">, "processing"=>nil, "approval"=>#<Milestone id: 657709, data_type: "approval">, "live"=>nil}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest way I know to do this is:

```
hash = @status_array.inject({}) do |result_hash, status| 
  result_hash[status] = @part_milestones.select { |milestone| milestone.data_type == status }.first
  result_hash
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [zip](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/zip) to merge the arrays into two dimensional and then use the following to convert into hash

```
Hash[@status_array.zip(@part_milestones)]
```

Documentation for [Hash[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D)

**UPDATE:**

just realized that its not a one to one mapping

```
hash = {}
@status_array.each do |status|
   hash[status] = @part_milestone.find{|milestone| milestone.data_type == status}
end
```

Answer (score -1):

`@part_milestones.sort_by &:data_type` should do the trick